# Value out of range for int in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

Normally whilst programming in LibGDX, passing the Color class an integer of a hex value works just fine:

```
new Color(0xeaeaeaff);
```

But doing this from Clojure...

```
(Color. 0xeaeaeaff)
```

... generates the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for int: 3,941,264,128. Sure that value does look out of range, very much so. But when I normally do it from Java, there is no problem at all?

The Clojure value is defined like so:

```
(def color 0xff00ffff)
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0xeaeaeaff` in Java represents a negative number: `-353703169` and causes overflow in Clojure (Java is just overflowing it to a negative number).

In your case `0xeaeaeaff` in Java is equal to `-353703169` in base 10. You can write it just as `-353703169` in Clojure, or in base 16 as `-16r15151501`.

You can use `unchecked-int` as pointed out by noisesmith.

Comment: In Clojure, -16r353703169 is way out of range. Perhaps you mean -16reaeaeaff? Still, however, the value it validates to is out of range.

Comment: Sorry for a typo. I have fix it - it should be `-16r15151501` as `353703169` base 10 is equal to `15151501` base 16.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to do some form av hex notation instead of first having to validate a hex validated integer through Java? That is, is it possible to write something similar to -16reaeaeaff validating to the 0xeaeaeaff of Java?

Comment: `0xeaeaeaff` is out of range and when casted to `int` in Java causes overflow to negative number. You might try `(Integer/parseUnsignedInt "eaeaeaff" 16)` which behaves similarly (requires Java 8).

Comment: 0xeaeaeaff is a valid clojure numeric literal.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would delete my answer as yours is better but I cannot since it's marked as accepted. I will edit it then.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get the same value that Java would give you, with the same literal as the input, is to use `unchecked-int`. It will return a negative (overflowed) number, just like the original, rather than giving an out of bounds error.

```
+user=> (unchecked-int 0xeaeaeaff)
-353703169
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, using literal notation for hexadecimal numbers produces `int`s, so `0xeaeaeaff` is an int with the value `-353703169`, because it exceeds the max value for ints, overflows and becomes a negative int.
In Clojure `0xeaeaeaff` produces a long with the value `3941264127`.

The class `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color` of LibGDX has a constructor that expects an `int` but not one that expects a `long`, which you are passing to it in the Clojure case, hence the exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value out of range for int: 3,941,264,128.`

You could just pass `-353703169` to the constructor or use `(Integer/parseUnsignedInt "eaeaeaff" 16)` like Piotrek suggested, as it would probably be more convinient, possibly through a wrapper function:

```
(defn hex->int [arg]
    (Integer/parseUnsignedInt arg 16))
```

Comment: The explanation is good, but there is no need for this function: just use [`unchecked-int`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/unchecked-int), `(unchecked-int 0xeaeaeaff)`.